# Can SquashFS filesystems work with macOS El Capitan?

Tags: macos, homebrew, filesystem, mount, compression

I am converting some .tar.gz to [SquashFS](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/) (using squashfs from [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)) using xz compression because I want to be able to mount the archives and read the content without extrating and also because the compression is about 10% better in my case.

Now I only found one implementation of SquashFS for [OSXFuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/) [here](https://github.com/vasi/squashfuse).

I am wondering what sort of driver or shim or software would be needed to let macOS work in any way (and hopefully read+write) with SquashFS?

Answer (score 7):

If you have homebrew installed, it's as easy as running `brew install squashfs`, and then either `unsquashfs` or `mksquashfs` depending on if you want to extract or make a comrpessed filesystem.