# Has anyone gotten `squashfs` working in docker on macOS version 14.3 using Docker Desktop?

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source, docker

I am currently using a Docker container that requires `squashfs` to create the file system.

The container fails to start up correctly and displays this in the logs:

```
2024-02-01 08:09:53 mount: /mnt/sqfs: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'.
```

To debug, I ran `cat /proc/filesystems` in the docker container and it did not list `squashfs`.

I saw in [the release notes for version 4.27.0 of docker](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#for-all-platforms) (latest as of this question's writing):

> Bug fixes and enhancements
>
> For all platforms:
>
> - [...]
> - Re-added kernel modules for `btrfs`, `xfs`, `vfat`, `exfat`, `ntfs3`, `f2fs`, **`squashfs`**, `udf`, `9p` and `autofs`.

I learned from [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913641/enabling-squashfs-inside-docker) that

> A Docker container cannot have a different filesystem list than their host machine

so I assumed my mac was missing `squashfs`.

I then [installed squashfs with homebrew per this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212906/331689) but it still doesn't work.
Even after restarting docker, running `cat /proc/filesystems` in the docker container STILL does not list `squashfs`. It still also shows the error above as well.

How can I run a container requiring `squashfs` on an Intel Based Mac running Sonoma 14.3 and Docker Desktop for mac?

---

**EDIT:**
Please Note, Versions **4.27.0** and **4.27.1** of Docker for mac [have a known issue where docker crashes a few minutes after boot](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/7164). Beware if you are planning on installing these versions of docker.

---

**EDIT 2:**
Versions **4.27.2**  of Docker for mac has fixed the errors in versinos **4.27.0** and **4.27.1**. After installing it, I now see `squashfs` listed when I run `cat /proc/filesystems` in the docker container. My docker container still doesn't run properly though, and I now get a different error in my docker logs:

```
2024-02-13 11:54:40 mount: /mnt/sqfs: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Comment: There is no equivalent. [This looks a lot like an XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - Are you asking what mounted file systems exist or what the entire menu of possible filesystem types the OS natively handles without third party additions? That’s the X interpretation of your question that might be better to just ask Y as “Has anyone gotten squashfs working in docker on macOS version 14.3 and any version of docker?”

Comment: I also was going to say FUSE has issues with Sonoma, but that seems to be sorted… https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/977

Comment: The actual issue I am trying to solve is getting a container requiring squashfs to run in Docker on an Intel Mac running Sonoma 14.3. I was hoping to find a way to confirm installing `squashfs`via brew was successful / could be accessed by docker. I could change this question to instead be the "Y" part and make the "X" a separate question. I'm more familiar with Linux under the hood than mac, and so it would be nice to find a command that does list "the entire menu of possible filesystem types the OS natively handles".

Comment: Awesome - if no one bites, I would recommend two distinct questions, one covering each topic succinctly. Those get far more answers than a “trying to do this thing” and also need help with “that other side-question”. Let’s see what happens next couple days…

Answer (score 0):

The utility you're looking for is lsvfs(1), which "lists information about the currently loaded virtual file system modules." I don't know whether it would recognize the one you're asking about.